# Insert static content into a jQuery UI menu widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I need static content (text and image, really arbitrary HTML) to appear inside of a jQuery UI menu. This is not a menu item. It should not be clickable or participate in any other menu behavior.

I found that adding the class `ui-state-disabled` disables the item but with two drawbacks:

1. It's still clickable (causing the menu to disappear).
2. It causes styling to be applied that I would need to undo.

Any ideas?

[Here's a demo of the issue.](http://jsfiddle.net/oy1qpfxL/) I can get "content" into the menu but it does not appear unaltered.

Comment: Please provide an example of your code, what you have tried, and what is not working.

Comment: @Twisty good idea. I just did that.

Comment: Ok, I see your fiddle. Not able to replicate the issue as you described it. Tried to adjust to do what you wanted, but it's really not clear what you want to accomplish. http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/oy1qpfxL/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to read through your post a few times. To display content that is not treated as a menu item, you can adjust the `items` option to exclude some.

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/oy1qpfxL/3/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu" style="width: 200px;">
  <li class="ui-state-disabled">
    <div>Toys (n/a)</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Books</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Clothing</div>
  </li>
  <li class="disabled">
    <div class="no-click">
      <button>
        x
      </button>
      <img src="https://jqueryui.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/images/logo-jquery-ui.png" />
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Electronics</div>
    <ul>
      <li class="ui-state-disabled">
        <div>Home Entertainment</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>Car Hifi</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>Utilities</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Movies</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Music</div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div>Rock</div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div>Alternative</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div>Classic</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>Jazz</div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div>Freejazz</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div>Big Band</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div>Modern</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>Pop</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-disabled">
    <div>Specials (n/a)</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#menu").menu({
  items: "> li:not(.disabled)"
});
```

So this will work to not disrupt the UI and allow you to have portions that can use HTML in the list. The alternative would be to add a class to all and set that as the `items`.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks! Sorry for the confusion. I described it to the best of my abilities.